# How and when do I use stateful and stateless classes?

Tags: class, oop, abap

In [Clean ABAP](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#dont-mix-stateful-and-stateless-in-the-same-class) it says to use stateful and stateless classes seperately and not mix them. What does that entail exactly?

Only class dependencies or immutables as attributes in stateless classes and the rest strictly functional with parameter passing?

And then in stateful classes operating mostly on private attributes without much use of returning parameters?

Cheers

Comment: In general stateful is bad, stateless is good. If you can avoid stateful in favour of stateless, do that.

Comment: Can you elaborate why, what do you use attributes for then? Seems contradictory to Object Orientation since my understanding is that data and operations belong inside the objects class. Maybe to clarify, when I say stateful I mean state mutations only inside the class itself.

Comment: Object orientation is not connected in any way to being stateful or stateless at least not directly. Object orientation is about encapsulation, abstraction and polymorphism. Loose coupling and cohesion are also very important which is hardly taught at the universities. I think the downsides of the statefulness are best proven in fiasco of stateful enterprise java beans. Try to google something on the latter. It might bring more clarity.

Comment: The linked article seems to be describing [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad, with no concrete detail or reproducible code. Expect that people will vote it down or even suggest to close it. The question might fit better into Stack Exchange’s Software Engineering site. Anyway, like most questions, it deserves an answer.

The Clean ABAP section primarily says to not mix the two paradigms in the *same class*. A single class should be either completely one or the other.

A class is stateless if its methods are functional, i.e. receive input and calculate output without changing the class‘s attributes.

Functional programming holds this up in all purity and requires e.g. that a method‘s input isn‘t changed but that the method produces new instances that represent the result. (Immutability)

Object-oriented programming is usually a little more relaxed. For example, your class will usually still be “stateless enough” if its methods wrote to `me->log`, the class kept a `me->buffer` to optimize performance, and had a method `add_empty_line( log )` that did `log->add( space )`.

These examples also show that a stateless class can have stateful attributes: `me->buffer` is most probably a stateful internal table or object.

You also do not have to keep stateless and stateful classes strictly separate in other regards. For example, you might have a stateless factory class that produces instances of stateful other classes.

A stateful class will optimally have only methods that work on the class‘s attributes.

Those methods may return something as well, it‘s not forbidden or unusual. For example, a `remove` method might not only remove a line from `me->entries` but might also return that removed entry, for further processing. A `find` method will of course return the found entry. Typical other patterns include returning `me` to enable method chaining.

In contrast, stateless methods that receive input and produce output *without* interacting with the class‘s attributes will often not fit well in a stateful class because they weaken the class’s cohesion: why do you put that method here, and not in some completely different class?